# Touchpad Gestures In Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I don’t have a touchscreen. How can I do gestures on my Windows 8 laptop’s touchpad?](https://superuser.com/questions/465619/i-dont-have-a-touchscreen-how-can-i-do-gestures-on-my-windows-8-laptops-touch)

Is there any way in windows 8 to disable/enable touchpad gestures,it makes things harder in my laptop.

Comment: I wish that I had rep enough on this site to vote to reopen this question. The so called duplicate is not a duplicate at all; it does not answer this question in any way.

Comment: @Guffa Ya,You're  right.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [Mouse and Keyboard Center 2.0+](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center) does not help you, you'll probably need to wait for a driver/software update from your laptop manufacturer.

Comment: The link doesn't lead anywhere any more.

Comment: @Guffa: Thanks for informing, I've edited the link. In future feel free to edit and update posts as long as you don't change their original meaning. If you lack the privileges, your suggested edit will be reviewed by someone and approved/rejected/improved. (I see you've been here far longer than me, so I guess you know all this already.)

Answer (score 0):

Touchpad gestures are usually controlled by software installed by the drivers for the touchpad. While these can vary between manufacturers, they will often extend the desktop Mouse control panel and so features can then be turned on or off through there.

To access this, switch to Desktop mode, move your pointer to the very bottom left of the screen and right click. From this menu, click Control Panel. At the top right, change the View By to either Large or Small icons, then click the Mouse icon.

Alternatively, some drivers add an icon for the Touchpad to the system tray, and you can access the controls via that.